# How do I get Artec e+ 48u to work on Xubuntu 14.10 (amd64)

Tags: xubuntu, scanner, udev, sane

Symptoms:

When I open Xsane, I get an [error that it cannot find my scanner](http://i57.tinypic.com/wswqb8.jpg).

simple-scan will open, but when I click the scan button I get a [failed to scan error](http://i62.tinypic.com/io20x2.jpg). The properties child window is what pops up when I click on the Change Scanner button next to the error.

I have been following this man page:

manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man5/sane-artec_eplus48u.5.html

I need the sane-artec_eplus48u - SANE backend.

The man page says to get that I need the following package:

> libsane-common-1.0.24-1.1ubuntu1_all

Synaptic says my version of libsane-common is 1.0.24-1.1ubuntu1. Note the missing '_all" at the end.

According to the page,

> If libusb-0.1.6 or later is installed, this section can be skipped.
>   The scanner should be found by sane-find-scanner without further 
>   actions.

The package name in Synaptic is: libusb-0.1-4
Syanaptic says installed version is: 2:0.1.12-24

I am a linux noob, but I think that means it is version 0.1.12-24 and should satisfy that requirement.  Please, correct me if that is wrong.

Here is what happens:

```
$ sane-find-scanner
...
found USB scanner (vendor=0x05d8, product=0x4003, chip=GT-6816) at libusb:002:004
...
```

And here is what happens with scanimage:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `artec_eplus48u:libusb:002:004' is a Artec E+ 48U flatbed scanner
```

The man page says the following files will be found after the back end installs:

```
/usr/local/etc/sane.d/artec_eplus48u.conf
```

This file is at the stated location.

Using the man page, I edited it and its current contents are:

```
# artec_eplus48u - SANE Backend configuration file
#
# SANE does not support hardware buttons
# Every device configuration must begin with a usb entry in this form:
# usb vendor-ID and product-ID

usb 0x05d8 0x4003

# The 48u needs a firmware file from its windows install disk called Artec48.usb

artecFirmwareFile /usr/share/sane/artec_eplus48u/Artec48.usb

# These are the recommended settings for the 48u according to the SANE Project:

redGamma 1.0
greenGamma 1.0
blueGamma 1.0
masterGamma 1.9
redOffset 0x28
greenOffset 0x2f
blueOffset 0x2f
redExposure 0xa7
greenExposure 0x116
blueExposure 0xdc
vendorString Artec
modelString E+ 48U
```

The man page also says that I should find these files after the back end install:

```
/usr/local/lib/sane/libsane-artec_eplus48u.a
/usr/local/lib/sane/libsane-artec_eplus48u.so
```

I do not find these files at the stated location or anywhere else.  Running Catfish as root, I find the following similarly, but not identically, named files in this very different location: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/

```
libsane-artec_eplus48u.1a
libsane-artec_eplus48u.so.1
libsane-artec_eplus48u.so.1.0.24
```

I see many posts about similar problems that have to do with permissions.  I also did find this in /usr/share/doc/libsane/README.linux

> One solution to set permissions on-the-fly is Linux udev which comes
>   with current distributions. SANE comes with a udev rules file in the
>   tools/udev directory which may be used by distributions or can be
>   copied to /etc/udev/rules.d manually. The file format is explained on
>   top of the file itself. Either you need libusb 0.1.12 or newer or
>   USB_DEVFS_PATH=/dev/bus/usb must be exported as a system-wide
>   environment variable.

Linux noob = having no idea how to find the proper folder or script they are referring to.

Xubuntu 14.10 does use udev, but again, as a noob, I do not fully understand the ramifications.

Temporarily changing permissions on the scanner device to allow all to rw does not change symptoms.

As a second test for permission problems, I ran simple-scan and xsane with and without sudo.  There is no change in the symptoms for either program.

According to the man page, I need a firmware file called Artec48.usb for the back end to use.  According to catfish there is one, and only one copy of Artec48.usb.  It is located in /usr/share/sane/artec_eplus48u/

It is owned by root, its group is root.  Owner has RW permission.  Group and others only have R permission.  MD5 hash for Artec48.usb is:  55113258bc41f30ef5f5be748e1b01ee

I have tried several different usb ports, and the results are the same on all of them.  My system has no usb3, only usb2, btw,  I saw that can cause problems with SANE also.

I have also tried deleting ~/.sane, restarting system.  Problems persist after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it came down to syntax, ugh!

In /usr/local/etc/sane.d/artec_eplus48u.conf each item EXCEPT the line beginning usb must be preceded by:

```
option
```

Revised version that works:

```
# artec_eplus48u - SANE Backend configuration file
#
# SANE does not support hardware buttons
# Every device configuration must begin with a usb entry in this form:
# usb vendor-ID and product-ID

usb 0x05d8 0x4003

# The 48u needs a firmware file from its windows install disk called Artec48.usb

option artecFirmwareFile /usr/share/sane/artec_eplus48u/Artec48.usb

# These are the recommended settings for the 48u according to the SANE Project:

option redGamma 1.0
option greenGamma 1.0
option blueGamma 1.0
option masterGamma 1.9
option redOffset 0x28
option greenOffset 0x2f
option blueOffset 0x2f
option redExposure 0xa7
option greenExposure 0x116
option blueExposure 0xdc
option vendorString Artec
option modelString E+ 48U
```